# Setting iTotalRecords in jquery data tables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I´m using jquery datatables to show some data in a table. I call a soap api and convert the result xml data to json like this.

```
var measures = $.xml2json(data);
$('#example').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "iTotalRecords": measures.iTotalRecords,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": measures.iTotalDisplayRecords
});
for (var i = 0; i < measures.aaData.ArrayOfstring.length; i++) {
    var serverarray = measures.aaData.ArrayOfstring[i].string;
    $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData(serverarray);
}
```

The data is displayed on the table but it shows only 10 records while `measures.iTotalRecords` returns "231".

What I´m doing wrong?

Comment: what value does `measure.iTotalDisplayRecords` display?

Comment: measures.iTotalDisplayRecords display "10". But I see on the foot of the table Showing 1 to 10 of 10 instead of 1 to 10 of 231.

Comment: Is there a way to set on-the-fly the total of records to show?

Comment: Have you viewed the xhr in developer tool to see how many records are being returned vs the iTotalRecords?

Comment: What if you set an alert for `measures.iTotalRecords` what does it show? Can you get a json response from the API instead of XML, then server side build the json array in the proper format and return it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m using ajax initialization and the total of records is showing correctly.

Comment: I´ve just changed the datatype of ajax call to json and it worked fine.

Comment: When I set an alert for `measures.iTotalRecords` it shows 231.